# Website issue - moving from local host to VM

Tags: wordpress, apache, virtualbox, lamp, portforwarding

I am hosting website using LAMP and Wordpress on a local machine with CentOS 7 installed, site works great no issues at all. I am trying to temporarily move (I want minimal downtime while making some changes) the site to a VM on VirtualBox. The host is Windows 10 and the guest is CentOS 7. I have the site up and running on the VM and all my content shows, it works perfect. The second I go into my router and change the port forwarding from the old server IP to the VM IP (using a bridged connection and static IP) my site loses most of the content on connections from inside and outside my network and even on the VM hosting the website. It basically changes to the default WordPress landing page with my site’s text, I guess you could say the theme/appearance disappears. The second I change the port forwarding IP back to the original server, the VM shows all content again. I have tried this on a WAMP Server install on a Windows 7 VM with the same result. As I said the operating system is CentOS 7, apache, mySQL, php, and phpmyadmin. I used updraft plus to backup several things from the site and also used the WordPress import/export tool. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I’m on day three with no luck making this work.

Comment: sounds like you haven't really rebuilt the wordpress installation on the vm. you don't need a import/export tool.

Backup all Files & Database  (i use Backupwordpress for this) and then load the files into the VM filesystem and the sql file into the VM database. make sure you got the right connection details in wp-config.php. and you should be set, assuming domain stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is domain name different on new machine comparing to that local?

If yes, you need to adopt it in database. WP migrate is great plugin to do that.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

Also you can look at Browser's Console to check if you have some errors. It sounds like your CSS and JS files are not loaded.

Comment: The domain is the same. I have compared all httpd, MySQL, and Wordpress config files on both machines and cannot see where I have anything set differently. The current server’s internal IP is 172.16.1.4 and the new VM server’s IP is 172.16.1.5. I I currently have a forwarding rule in my router that forwards requests on port 80 to 172.16.1.4. All I’m doing in the router is changing it from forwarding requests on port 80 from 1.4 to 1.5. The external IP is the same and the domain/URL is the same. To me, once I change the forwarding rule in my router the new server should take over, but it’s not.